# Why does SendwithUs make you define instance methods instead of class methods?

Tags: sendwithus

I'm reading how to use [SendWithUs](https://github.com/sendwithus/sendwithus_ruby_action_mailer)

Why do we have to define instance methods in the class instead of class methods when we never actually instantiate the class? Why does `SendWithUs` force us to use this odd convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sendwithus action mailer was designed to match the conventions outlined in the existing ruby [action mailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html). We also have a Ruby client [here](https://github.com/sendwithus/sendwithus_ruby) which you could use instead of the Sendwithus action mailer. This would allow you to call our API directly.